# Gather subtensor of padded tensor of variable-sized data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have some variable-length sequencial data of fixed tensor dimension.
Consider a list of tensors s_1, ..., s_b of a list of some fixed dimensional matrices [l_1,m,n], ..., [l_b,m,n].
For example

```
s_1 = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]] ]
s_2 = [ [[9,10],[11,12]], [[13,14],[15,16]], [[17,18],[19,20]] ]
```

Though the data is given in a padded form, like the following

```
S = [ [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[0,0],[0,0]]], 
    [[[9,10],[11,12]], [[13,14],[15,16]], [[17,18],[19,20]]] ]
l = [2,3]
```

where `S` is the tensor of padded lists of matrices and `l` is the 1-D tensor with `i`-th entry given by the length of sequence `i`.

Now, I want to extract a tensor given by the concatenation of the list of matrices. The result should be

```
[ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]], [[13,14],[15,16]], [[17,18],[19,20]] ]
```

This calculation will be done in a function for the `map` methode of a `tf.data.Dataset`.

What would be the correct approach to do this in tensorflow?
I thought of using `tf.boolean_mask` together with `tf.sequence_mask` but can't quite get the result I want. Maybe some clever use of `tf.gather_nd`?

**EDIT**

```
tf.boolean_mask(S,tf.sequence_mask(l))
```

seems to give the correct result, but I can only get it to work outside of a function passed to the `map` methode of `tf.data.Dataset`.

```
def _parse_SE(in_example_proto):
    S = ...
    l = ... #obtain S and l from the record

    return tf.tuple([S,l])
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("test.txt")
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_SE)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([], [None], [], [None,n,s]))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
[S_bat, l_bat] = iterator.get_next()
wanted_bat = tf.boolean_mask(S_bat,tf.sequence_mask(l_bat)) # when evaluated wanted_bat stores the wanted concatenation
```

does work. But if I try to make the modification inside of the mapping function I just get `S` again:

```
def _parse_SE(in_example_proto):
    S = ...
    l = ... #obtain S and l from the record
    wanted = tf.boolean_mask(S,tf.sequence_mask(l))

    return tf.tuple([wanted,l])
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("test.txt")
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_SE)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([], [None], [], [None,n,s]))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
[wanted_bat, l_bat] = iterator.get_next() # when evaluated wanted_bat just contains S_bat of the previous example
```

**EDIT 2**

The second approach won't work as the function `_parse_SE` passed to `map` will be applied to each one element of the batch at the time and not to the *whole* batch. Thus we can not refactor the batch inside of `_parse_SE`.

Comment: Try passing `maxlen=tf.shape(S)[1]` to `tf.sequence_mask`.

Comment: Thanks I tested it, and it did not work. Though I think I know where the problem lies. The function passed to `map` only applies to each one element of the batch at the time, not to the whole batch. Thus the solution can not be transfered inside... I guess the question is resolved

Comment: Ah wait I think the problem is you are using `padded_batch`. I think you should use [`flat_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) after that to "concatenate" all `S` elements.